# Перенос данных с одной формы на другую

Tags: javascript, html, css

Да, я уже задавал этот вопрос, но в этот раз с самим кодом, ибо ответы не помогли. Первая форма:

```
<form action="https://www.f-elizaveta.ru/pay" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Сумма заказа">
  <input type="submit" name="button" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Вторая форма(платежка):

```
<body onload="load()">
  <script src="https://securepay.tinkoff.ru/html/payForm/js/tinkoff_v2.js"></script>
  <form class="TinkoffPayForm" name="TinkoffPayForm" >
    <input class="tinkoffPayRow" type="hidden" name="terminalkey" value="TinkoffBankTest">
    <input class="tinkoffPayRow" type="hidden" name="frame" value="true">
    <input class="tinkoffPayRow" type="hidden" name="language" value="ru">
    <input class="tinkoffPayRow" type="text" placeholder="Сумма заказа" name="amount" required>
    <input class="tinkoffPayRow" type="text" placeholder="Номер заказа" name="order">
    <input class="tinkoffPayRow" type="text" placeholder="Описание заказа" name="description">
    <input class="tinkoffPayRow" type="text" placeholder="ФИО плательщика" name="name">
    <input class="tinkoffPayRow" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="email">
    <input class="tinkoffPayRow" type="text" placeholder="Контактный телефон" name="phone">
    <input class="tinkoffPayRow" type="submit" value="Оплатить" id="sub">
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function load() {
      let params = new URL("https://f-elizaveta.ru/garantiya").searchParams;
      let firstInput = params.get('price');
    alert(firstInput);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Не знаю, в чем проблема и решить не могу уже долгое время. Переход между страницами осуществляется, но текст так и не записывается.  firstInput выдает значение null.

Comment: Ничего что ты суешь ссылку которую сам написал в new Url?

Comment: @Vadim в new URL адрес первой формы

Comment: Я про то, что адрес введен вручную и НЕ имеет .searchParams, т.е. ты одну и ту же строку тыркаешь, а не из юрла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойство URL([аргумент]).searchParams ищет параметры по адресу аргумента. В адресе "https://f-elizaveta.ru/garantiya" никаких параметров нет. Вместо этого нужно запрашивать расположение страницы, то есть **document.location**.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function load() {
      let params = new URL(document.location).searchParams;
      let firstInput = params.get('price');
    alert(firstInput);
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, с этим теперь понятно. А что нужно делать чтобы инпут был равен firstInput? Через обычный getElement?

Comment: Не понял что Вы хотите этим сказать.

Если Вас интересует как установить значение элемента формы, то - да, нужно сначала ее найти, а потом присвоить требуемое значение. 

https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/416375/